# How to copy an Azure Image from one region to another region

Tags: azure

I have a (sysprepped/generalized) server template in an Azure Image in an Azure region (Canada Central). I would like to use it to create an Azure VM in a different Azure region (Central US). It doesn't work.

So, I need that Azure Image to also reside in Central US. How can I copy my Azure image from one Azure region to another?

Answer (score 10):

You can use azure [cli extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/tree/master/src/image-copy) to copy images between region

```
az extension add --name image-copy-extension
az image copy --source-resource-group mySources-rg --source-object-name myImage --target-location uksouth northeurope --target-resource-group "images-repo-rg" --cleanup
```

**EDIT:
There is a new way to share images between regions, [Shared Image Gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/shared-image-galleries).

You can decide which regions will have access to the image with the `--target-regions` option.

Comment: hey just a quick question. If I create a snap shot of source Image, I can still be using it right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, do you mean copying the snapshots between regions? I think that it support copying image or vm only.

Comment: Thanks for replying. What I meant was , if we generalize the VM to create an image, then the VM will no longer be usable right? Similarly I thought that if we create a snapshot of the Image, then Image will also be no longer usable.But I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no direct option via portal or a simple commandlet.

But you can achieve this via [Azcopy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azcopy-5-1-release/) tool. You will actually copy the VM image from a storage account in region A to another storage account in region B.

Another option via code is to use the [Azure storage data movement library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement).

Another option is used to the unplanned failover option to another region using the [azure site recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-migrate-azure-to-azure). But this option has some constraints.(mentioned in the link)

Comment: How do I get to the storage account and the disk from the Azure Image?

Comment: whenever a VM is created a storage account is associated with it. You can find it from the portal or use powershell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997810/get-storage-account-of-azure-vm

Answer (score 0):

As Aravind said, for now, there is no command that could copy image to another location. You need copy image's VHD to new location and create a new image. Please refer to the following steps:

1.Use the image to create a VM in the current location.

2.Create a storage account in westeurope.

3.Stop VM and copy VM's managed disk to new storage account.

```
$sas = Grant-AzureRmDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName "[ResourceGroupName]" -DiskName "[ManagedDiskName]" -DurationInSecond 3600 -Access Read  
$destContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName "[StorageAccountName]" -StorageAccountKey "[StorageAccountAccessKey]"
$blobcopy=Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer "[ContainerName]" -DestContext $destContext -DestBlob "[NameOfVhdFileToBeCreated].vhd"
```

Note: Use image to create VM, the OS disk is managed disk.

4.Use the VHD to create a new VM, you could use the [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-existing-vnet) to do this.

5.Use the VM to create a new image. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-custom-images).

Note: If you have image's original VHD, you could copy it to new location and use it to create a new VM, then re-create image.

Comment: This answer was written in 2017, is this updated?