# azure cli az image copy got an error output: ERROR: Resource DISK is not found

Tags: azure

i am using `az image copy` of Azure CLI to copy image from one region to another , thanks to [How to copy an Azure Image from one region to another region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720966/how-to-copy-an-azure-image-from-one-region-to-another-region) , i add the extesnion using

```
az extension add --name image-copy-extension
```

and made the command :

```
az image copy --source-resource-group "<src-resource-group-name>" --source-object-name "server-with-appache" --target-location "Southeast Asia" --target-resource-group "<target-resource-group-name>" --cleanup
```

and got this error :

```
Getting os disk id of the source vm/image
Data disks in the source detected, but are ignored by this extension!
Creating source snapshot
command failed: ['/opt/az/bin/python3', '-m', 'azure.cli', 'snapshot', 'create', '--name', 'server-with-appache_os_disk_snapshot', '--resource-group', '<src-resource-group-name>', '--source', '/subscriptions/d371652e-b4a0-4e59-b82d-4b5ddb762756/resourceGroups/<src-resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/vm-for-iamge-with-apache_disk1_b6938afa59dd4aa385fb58cf4ea6afe6', '--output', 'json', '--tags', 'created_by=image-copy-extension']
output: ERROR: Resource vm-for-iamge-with-apache_disk1_b6938afa59dd4aa385fb58cf4ea6afe6 is not found.

The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:

Command '['/opt/az/bin/python3', '-m', 'azure.cli', 'snapshot', 'create', '--name', 'server-with-appache_os_disk_snapshot', '--resource-group', '<src-resource-group-name>', '--source', '/subscriptions/d371652e-b4a0-4e59-b82d-4b5ddb762756/resourceGroups/<src-resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/vm-for-iamge-with-apache_disk1_b6938afa59dd4aa385fb58cf4ea6afe6', '--output', 'json', '--tags', 'created_by=image-copy-extension']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 206, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 603, in execute
    raise ex
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 661, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 654, in _run_job
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 631, in _run_job
    result = cmd_copy(params)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 305, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 485, in default_command_handler
    return op(**command_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.azure/cliextensions/image-copy-extension/azext_imagecopy/custom.py", line 82, in imagecopy
    run_cli_command(cli_cmd)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.azure/cliextensions/image-copy-extension/azext_imagecopy/cli_utils.py", line 35, in run_cli_command
    raise ex
  File "/home/ubuntu/.azure/cliextensions/image-copy-extension/azext_imagecopy/cli_utils.py", line 21, in run_cli_command
    cmd_output = check_output(cmd, stderr=STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/az/bin/python3', '-m', 'azure.cli', 'snapshot', 'create', '--name', 'server-with-appache_os_disk_snapshot', '--resource-group', '<src-resource-group-name>', '--source', '/subscriptions/d371652e-b4a0-4e59-b82d-4b5ddb762756/resourceGroups/<src-resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/vm-for-iamge-with-apache_disk1_b6938afa59dd4aa385fb58cf4ea6afe6', '--output', 'json', '--tags', 'created_by=image-copy-extension']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

- names of resourtce group was replaced for privacy , i have storage account's in both resource group src and target , no both from same types since the source was create about 5 month ago. anyone encounter this issue ?
- note - i have already deleted the source VMof the image and it's disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the issue , you can't transfer images like this , just the disks that the images was made from , what you can do is make the images shared gallery images and then they are cross region shared like in this tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/shared-images